# Why won't my son eat?

Tags: toddler, food

My son turns one in five days. Since yesterday he has started turning his head and blocking our attempts to bring a spoon or fork up to his mouth.

Sometimes he will open his mouth and let us put food in it. This is quickly followed by him pushing all of the food out of his mouth and grabbing what he can with his hand. He then drops the food on the floor.

I thought he was wanting to feed himself, but handing him the food results in a similar trip to the floor.

My wife took him to the pediatrician today because we thought he might be sick but the doctor didn't find anything (our son was happy and playful for him) and used the opportunity to do his one year checkup. He said everything was fine, but our son still doesn't want to eat.

He drinks from his sippy cup for a few seconds before pushing it away, too.

I think this may be my fault as I fed him a bite if my food last week during dinner that had Tapatio sauce on it. I wasn't trying to hurt him, but he was visibly uncomfortable with the bite. If I'm the reason this is happening, I'm ready to receive my "Worst Dad of the Year" mug.

Why won't he eat?

Comment: If the pediatrician says he's fine, then "he'll eat once he gets hungry enough" is the right answer. Kids go through ravenous and "won't eat" periods, it's totally normal.

Comment: Exactly. Don't stress about it - just keep offering a variety of things. He might just have less of an appetite for the moment.

Comment: I'd argue that this question isn't close enough to the suggested question to be a duplicate. There is a big difference between a 5 year old and a 1 year old.

Comment: @justkt The first sentence of this question is "My son turns **one** in *five days*", and it is tagged "toddler" (which is age-specific for 1 to 3 years of age).  The linked question is about a one year old.  I don't think either are about 5 year olds.

Comment: @Boefett - I clearly misread. Feel free to delete the comment thread.

Answer (score 1):

I gave my kid a spoonful of mustard and he cried. It happens, don't worry.

Really, dont worry: From the description I would bet your kid is just playing with your worries. He likes to feel that you are concerned and the more you are the more he or she will play this game.